SvelteKit: error when starting dev server: Error: write EOF / adapter-cloudflare
When trying to start a SvelteKit project of mine I am getting this error:
C:\...\svelte-app>npm run dev

> svelte-mvp@0.0.1 dev
> vite dev

error when starting dev server:
Error: write EOF
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16)

Versions:
node --version
v20.11.0

I can start other SvelteKit projects just fine and I can create a new SvelteKit project and start that without issue. Any ideas what this error even means and how to fix it?

Update #1
The error is related to the Cloudflare adapter:
svelte.config.js
// This line causes the issues: 
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare';

Using '@sveltejs/adapter-auto' is a local workaround but the underlying issues is still unknown.

Could you please provide a reproducible example?

@mvioole Hey I have updated my question with a new insight. The cloudflare adapter seems to be the issue.

Looking through the internet I found out that this kind of error is due to a syntax error, such as missing closing tags or quotes. Are you absolutely sure that nothing like that is happening?

Also maybe do an npm update, or update on just that package? Perhaps the package needs to be fixed, like as if it was modified somehow?

Looks like a caching issue to me. Have you tried deleting the node_modules/.vite directory?
